# Need to simplify and clean up this code

Tags: python

I am a Python beginner and need to clean up and simplify this code but I have no clue how to, so any feedback would be apreciated!

```
print ("Type in four inputs.")
word_first = raw_input("What is your first input? ")
word_second = raw_input("What is your second input? ")
word_third = raw_input("What is your third input? ")
word_fourth = raw_input("What is your fourth input? ")

list_of_words = [word_first, word_second, word_third, word_fourth]
print
print sorted(list_of_words, key=len)

def average(numbers):
    return sum(numbers)/len(numbers)

all_words = word_first, word_second, word_third, word_fourth 
words_total = word_first, word_second, word_third, word_fourth.split()
length_words = [len(word) for word in words_total]

word_first_length = len(word_first)
word_second_length = len(word_second)
word_third_length = len(word_third)
word_fourth_length = len(word_fourth)
total_letters = word_first_length + word_second_length + word_third_length + word_fourth_length
average_length = total_letters / 4
print
print ("Shortest input is: ") + (min((word for word in list_of_words if word), key=len))
print ("Average length is %.1f.") %(average_length)
```

Comment: Check out https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for code review.

Comment: I tried golfing it. The result fit's nicely in a comment: `W = [raw_input("Input %s: " % (i + 1)) for i in range(4)]; print("avg len: %s\nshortest: %s" % (sum([len(w) for w in W]) / float(len(W)), min(W, key=len)))` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a for loop.

```
min = 100000000
total = 0
repeat = 4
for i in range(repeat):
    len_input = len(input("Number: ")) 
    if len_input < min:
         min = len_input 
    total += number
print(min)
print(total/number)
```

Some notes about a for loop

- you can use the value of i
- range has the following optional parameters (start,stop,step) but range(4) will assume start is 0 and step is 1. The array generated will not include the stop value. For example `range(0, 30, 5) => [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25]`
- a list comprehension using a for loop does not require a condition `[word for word in list_of_words]` will also work.